# If $I=\langle q\rangle$ then $\{q\}$ is a Gröbner basis for I.

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis

I've been reading Cox "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms" and I've got stuck on this problem.

It looks easy but I don't know what to do.

I tried finding a contradiction on remainder being not equal to $0$ but I'm having doubts.

Comment: What definition of Gröbner basis are you using? And did you try directly verifying the definition for principal ideals?

Comment: $\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}\subset I$ is a Gröbner basis for I if $LT(I)=\left\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_n)\right\rangle$.

I tried verifying the condition by showing that at least one of $LT(g_i)|LT(g)$ but it didn't pan out for me.

Comment: @AndrewLi I think in general $rLT(q)$ is not the leading term of any polynomial so I don't think it can be an element of $LT(I)$, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

- The [condition that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Formal_definition) each member of $\ I\ $  has remainder $\ 0\ $ with respect to $\ \{g\}\ $ looks like it might be one of the easiest to verify.
- For polynomials in two or more indeterminates, the proof that every element of $\ \langle g\rangle\ $ leaves a remainder of $\ 0\ $ with respect to $\ \{g\}\ $ is closely analogous to that for the case of univariate polynomials.

Comment: I tried this but It's not clear to me why for an arbitrary element $f\in I$ we have that $LT(g)|LT(f)$, I know that $f=kg$ but in general we may have an element of $I=\left\langle f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\right\rangle$ such that division by an arbitrary monomial order may have remainder.

Comment: If $\ f=kg\ $ then $\ LT(f)=LT(k)LT(g)\ $.

Comment: Of course! Thanks!